# structured streaming + kafka integration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to use structured streaming with Kafka to read and write the messages. If I'm using structured streaming, spark stores the offsets to checkpoint directory.
?

1. If I wanted to use the consumer group to process the Kafka messages for a topic, How will it work? here we are not committing offsets to Kafka and if we lose checkpoint directory how will it be fault-tolerant?
2. How the checkpoint location should be ? can I use the same checkpoint directory for multiple jobs or multiple consumers?
3. If I configure startingOffsets to earliest, will every restart of the job reads from the beginning because we are not committing the offsets to Kafka?

Answer (score -1):

1. By default structured streaming generate a unique group id to read data from kafka which ensure that no other consumer is reading data through that group id. Optionally you can set the kafka group id to read data from kafka but you have to make sure that no other consumer using that group id otherwise it might possible that your job can read only part of the data. Structured streaming using hdfs as a checkpoint dir and hdfs replication factor make sure that even if one node is down the data will be replicated to other nodes and that makes checkpointing fault-tolerant.
2. You have to provide checkpoint location while you writing to any sink and spark keeps the range of offsets processed on that trigger. If you will provide the same checkpoint location for multiple job then it would be problematic if consuming from same topic.
3. By configuring startingOffsets to earliest it always starts from the starting point every time. It doesn't matter where you are committing the offsets.